# Remove/Add hover after toggle Jquery

Tags: jquery, click, hover, toggle

I have this css:

```
.disable {
          properties
          }

.comment_action:hover {
                       properties
                       }
```

I have this jQuery:

```
//comment button index disable
$("#mydiv").toggle(function() {
 $(this).find(".comment_action").addClass('disable');   
},
function(){
 $(this).find(".comment_action").removeClass('disable');
});
```

The problem for me is that when I doing click the **.comment_action:hover is not disappear or removed**. I want that If I doing click on the class **.comment_action:hover dissapear** and if I doing click again the **.comment_action:hover appear.**

Comment: The CSS `:hover` selector applies its associated rules to an element when it is in a hovered state. That is, when the mouse is over the element. The CSS listed in the `:hover` part of your code should only be applied when the mouse is over the element. Are you sure you're phrasing your question properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an `!important` added to properties you want to override in the `:hover` psuedo-selector...

Because `:hover` takes precedence, even if `.disabled` is applied.

Also your javascript should be calling find with `.comment_action` instead of `comment_action`

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TN4rh/11/

Comment: Thank you, the problem is fixed its !important the magic word :D Regards

Answer (score 0):

Better solution would be toggle the class. What you are trying to do can be done in **one line**.

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".comment_action").toggleClass('disable');       
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/QH5FY/)

:)

Answer (score 0):

You are telling your browser to add hover effects to `.comment_action`. This is what is going to happen to all elements with that class, regardless of it having any other class such as `.disable`.

Solution: add the :hover properties to a new `.enable` class. Instead of just removing and adding `.disable`, also add and remove `.enable`.

```
.disable {
          properties
          }

.enable:hover {
                properties
                }
```