# jQuery remove class on 2nd click and disable hover on 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to remove class 'active' when you click on the checkbox the 2nd time, the same way Pinterest does it for Twitter/Facebook checkboxes when a user adds a pin:
[image]

Adding 'active' class on click is easy. However, I couldn't figure how to remove it once it was added. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$(".add_link_twitter.active").click(function(e) {  
      $(this).removeClass(activePostTwitter); 
    });
```

I have two questions:

1. How to remove the 'active' css class on the 2nd click on the
   checkbox?
2. How to disable '.add_link_twitter:hover' when the Twitter
   checkbox is selected?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the jQuery:

```
var postTwitter = ".add_link_twitter"; 
var activePostTwitter = "active"; 
$(postTwitter).click(function(e) {  
  $(this).addClass(activePostTwitter); 
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<label class="add_link_twitter">
<input type="checkbox" name="publish_to_twitter" class="publish_to_twitter"><span>Share on Twitter</span>
</label>
```

Here's the css:

```
.add_link_twitter{
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    bottom:16px;
    color: #a19486;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-color: #F0EDE8;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 7px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.active {
    border-color: #468BD0;
    color: #468BD0;
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
}

.add_link_twitter:hover
{
    color: #A19486;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-color: #C2B1A2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 7px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(postTwitter).click(function(e) {  
  $(this).addClass(activePostTwitter); 
});
```

use

```
$(postTwitter).click(function(e) {  
  $(this).toggleClass(activePostTwitter); 
});
```

EDIT:

The event triggers twice per click, probably because of event propagation. To work around this, assign the handler to the `input` and have it change the class of its parent:

```
$(postTwitter + " input").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass(activePostTwitter);
});
```

Confirm jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bpfqB/

Comment: Actually, I tried that (after reading this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679246/remove-add-hover-after-toggle-jquery) and it didn't work. When the checkbox selected, it doesn't even add the 'active' class. Any clues?

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot!! Works like magic. Any idea how to tackle the 2nd question: How to disable '.add_link_twitter:hover' when the 'active' class is added?

Comment: @Arman Just set the default styles for `.add_link_twitter .active:hover` and they should take precedence.

Comment: I did ´.add_link_twitter .active:hover', but it disabled hover altogether. Essentially, I want hover to be enabled for '.add_link_twitter', but disabled for '.add_link_twitter .active'. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for both your questions:

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    var $postTwitter = $("label.add_link_twitter");

    $postTwitter.find("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
        if($("input.publish_to_twitter").is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
        }
    });

    $postTwitter.hover(
        function() {
            if($("input.publish_to_twitter").is(":checked")) {
                return;
            }

            $(this).addClass("hover");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        });
});
```

You need to make some changes to your CSS though, you have to do the hovering with jQuery (skip the CSS hover).

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/s2X3S/1/)

Comment: Well, it works, thanks, but the thing is I can't just paste it as is into $(document).ready(function() {}. Do you know any workarounds?

Comment: @Arman Why can't you paste it into your `$(document).ready(function() {}` function?